# Computing the kernel and image of a linear transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have a linear transformation $f:R^3 \to R^3$ , $f(x,y,z) = (2x+2z, x+z, x + 3y -2z)$. 
 I need to find out Ker and Im of $f$.

I found out $\ker(f) = \{(-a,a,a) \mid a \in \mathbb R\}$; $\dim(\ker(f)) = 1$.

For image I wrote : $\text{im} (f) = \{y \in \mathbb R \mid f(x) = y\}$. And now I have to solve the following system:

\begin{cases} 2x + 2z &=& y'_1 \\ 
x  +  z &=& y'_2 \\
x  + 3y - 2z &=& y'_3 \end{cases}
I assume that  $\dim(\text{im}(f)) = \text{rg}(f) = 2$, but how do I find $y'_1, y'_2$ and $y'3$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to solve any linear system to have a basis of $\operatorname{Im} f$.

A basis is given by a maximal set of linearly independent columns of the representative matrix of the linear transformation, the same matrix of the linear system you wrote.